# How to change QTableView scrollbar position to be below header?

Tags: qt, qt5, qtableview, qscrollarea

How to change scrollbar position from next to header

[image]

to below header?

[image]

Any ideas how to implement this are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in qss (I assume your header has 50px height with a blue color) :

```
QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical {
    padding-top: 50px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: blue;
}
QScrollBar::vertical {
    margin-top: 50px;
    padding-top: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below hack:

1. Put the `QTableView` in a `QVBoxLayout`
2. Get horizontal header view from QTableView using `horizontalHeader()`
3. Insert the horizontal header view in the `QVBoxLayout` on top of `QTableView`